# Not yet translated vs Not translated yet

Tags: adverbs, word-order

In an item list on a web page, I have a colored legend:

- green - Translated and published
- red - Not yet translated

Is it correct usage? Or should I say "not translated yet"? Or maybe both are acceptable?

Comment: @CatfishFTW: Please do not use inline code formatting on this site except for extremely unusual special purposes.

Comment: @NathanTuggy  like what?

Comment: @CatfishFTW: tables (which you should usually avoid), quoting single and double quotes surrounding text (which can usually be re-arranged in a better way), and a few other weird things I can't think of off-hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you are using is

> not yet *verb-ed*
>   not *verb-ed* yet

Both are acceptable.

> not yet translated

has more the feeling that the translation is underway or almost finished but still being worked on, as in "not yet finished" which is an idiom.

> not translated yet

has more the feeling of the translation has not started yet, as in "not done yet".

In both cases the final translation does not exist yet.